# Super and Subclasses

Tags: python, subclass, superclass

I have been given an assignment that asks us to deal with three individual classes: `Point`, `Rectangle` and `Canvas`. I was just wondering if anyone could help me get a general understanding as how they are suppose to interact. The programming language is Python 3

Here are the outputs expected:

```
>>>r1=Rectangle(Point(), Point(1,1), "red")
>>>r1
Rectangle(Point(0,0),Point(1,1),'red')
```

another example would be:

```
>>> r3=Rectangle(Point(), Point(2,1), "red")
>>> r3.get_perimeter()
6
```

Comment: what language is this? Python?

Comment: Yes, I should have added that!

Comment: Does a `Point` sound like a kind of `Rectangle`? Does a `Canvas` sound like a kind of `Point`? Do any of these things seem like they would be sensibly implemented as a special kind of one of the other things? No? Then there shouldn't be any super/subclass relations between them.

Comment: @user2357112, that makes sense, so there's no need for a subclass then? How does python understand point(1,1) for example then as a parameter being implemented into rectangle?

Comment: @MatteoColombi subclasses are an "is a" relationship. A Customer ***is a*** Person. An Arm ***is a*** BodyPart. Is a Point a Rectangle or a Canvas or neither? Repeat for Canvas and Rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the interactions between objects of type `A` and the other types, if you ask yourself: What does object of type `A` need to be defined?

One of the possible implementations of your `Rectangle` is to define rectangle via two opposite corners, which are points in the plane and can be of type `Point`. `Point` itself, could be represented as pair of numbers. The obvious definitions are now

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xCoordinate = x
        self.yCoordinate = y



class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, southwest, northeast, colour):
        self.bottomLeftCorner = southwest
        self.upperRightCorner = northeast
        self.fill = colour
```

and you can define

```
rect = Rectangle(Point(0,1), Point(4,212), "red")
```

Following the upper definition, to define `Rectangle`, one needs two `Point` objects and one `String`. No superclass/subclass relation is involved.

Since you did not provide any examples of `Canvas`, I cannot help you more, but I think that you can do it on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had began to do something along the lines that you have so at least now I know I'm on the right track